# UEC - Ubuntu 10.10 - node registration problem

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, eucalyptus

I am trying to setup a private cloud on two servers. All components register as expected except for my node. I've found one person who had the same exact problem using Ubuntu 10.10 during the beta, but none of the responses to that posting have fixed the issue. I've included below the text of the post I am referring to as well as a link to the entire post/responses.

POST:
"I have a two computer system where one server is CC + CLC + SC and the other server is NC. Both servers are dual core PCs with 4GB RAM.

I installed UEC 10.10 beta with the Eucalyptus 2.0 that comes with it and upgraded it from the repositories so that it is up to date as of 09/20/2010.

I was able to get everything working except that the node controller does not seem to be registered properly. Below are the command line results.

root@cloudcontroller:/var/log/eucalyptus# euca_conf --list-walruses
registered walruses:
Walrus 192.168.1.143
root@cloudcontroller:/var/log/eucalyptus# euca_conf --list-clusters
registered clusters:
cluster1 192.168.1.143
root@cloudcontroller:/var/log/eucalyptus# euca_conf --list-nodes

root@cloudcontroller:/var/log/eucalyptus# euca_conf --list-scs
registered storage controllers:
cluster1 192.168.1.143

root@cloudcontroller:/var/log/eucalyptus# euca-describe-availability-zones verbose
AVAILABILITYZONE cluster1 192.168.1.143
AVAILABILITYZONE |- vm types free / max cpu ram disk
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.small 0000 / 0000 1 512 4
AVAILABILITYZONE |- c1.medium 0000 / 0000 1 512 5
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.large 0000 / 0000 2 512 10
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.xlarge 0000 / 0000 2 1024 20
AVAILABILITYZONE |- c1.xlarge 0000 / 0000 4 2048 20

When I try to manually register the Node controller I get:

root@cloudcontroller:/var/log/eucalyptus# euca_conf --register-nodes 192.168.1.100

INFO: We expect all nodes to have eucalyptus installed in //var/lib/eucalyptus/keys for key synchronization.

Trying rsync to sync keys with "192.168.1.100"...done.
If I try to do the automatic discovery, I get the following issue with IPV6 formatted address.

root@cloudcontroller:/var/log/eucalyptus# euca_conf --discover-nodes
New node found on fe80::21e:4fff:febb:82a2; add it? [Yn] y

INFO: We expect all nodes to have eucalyptus installed in //var/lib/eucalyptus/keys for key synchronization.

Trying rsync to sync keys with "fe80::21e:4fff:febb:82a2"...ssh: Could not resolve hostname fe80: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
failed.

Trying scp to sync keys to: eucalyptus@fe80::21e:4fff:febb:82a2://var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fe80: Name or service not known
lost connection
failed.

ERROR: could not synchronize keys with fe80::21e:4fff:febb:82a2!
The configuration will not have this node.
Hint: to setup passwordless login to the nodes as user eucalyptus, you can
run the following commands on node fe80::21e:4fff:febb:82a2:
sudo -u eucalyptus mkdir -p ~eucalyptus/.ssh
sudo -u eucalyptus tee ~eucalyptus/.ssh/authorized_keys > /dev/null <"

URL:
http://open.eucalyptus.com/forum/uec-1010-beta-eucalyptus-20-node-controller-issues

I'm completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

UEC's automatic discovery ($euca_conf --discover-nodes) will discover your nodes twice; once with the IPv4 address and once for the IPv6 address.

Just say **'yes'** to the IPv4 and **'no'** to the IPv6.